# Code is copying the header to every record

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have a page which is retrieving Data from some tables of MySQL and display it for

user but in here The while condition is defined above so its copying the header to every

record.

Can any one check my code and tell me where the problem is ?

Below is the code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
  ob_start();
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
  echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL= ../../spd/myaccount.php">';
  exit();
}
else 
{
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
require_once('../../Admin Panel/db.php');

$query = "SELECT 
   properties.PropertyID,
   properties.PropertyType,
   properties.PropertyDealType,
   properties.Status,
   properties.PropostedPrice,
   properties.PropertyStatus,
   properties.RemoteEmployeeEmail,
   properties.PropertyDealerName,
   properties.PropertyOwnerName,
   remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeID

   FROM remoteemployees,
        properties

   WHERE remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeEmail = properties.RemoteEmployeeEmail   

   AND  properties.RemoteEmployeeEmail = '".$email."'

   AND  properties.Status= 'Active'

   AND  properties.PropertyStatus= 'APPROVED'


   ORDER BY properties.PropertyID
   ";


  $query_run = $connection->query($query);
  if( $connection->error ) exit( $connection->error );
  while($row=$query_run->fetch_assoc()) {
                $count      =   $queryrun->num_rows;          // Taking the number of queries returened by the result
                $array[]    =   $res;
         ?>


<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">
<div style="float:left;"><font color="#000000">Welcome: <?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?> 
</font>
</div>
<div style="float:right; color:#999; width:600px; margin-left:155px;">


<a href="#" style="  font: 15px verdana;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  cursor:pointer;">My Contract Copy</a>

<a href="#" style="  font: 15px verdana;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  cursor:pointer;">My Property List</a>

<a href="#" style="  font: 15px verdana;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  cursor:pointer;">My Trans.History</a>

<a href="Remote Employee profile.php?RemoteEmployeeid=<?php echo $row['RemoteEmployeeID'] ?>" style="  font: 15px verdana;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  cursor:pointer;">My Profile</a>

<a href="logout.php" style="  font: 15px verdana;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  cursor:pointer;">Logout</a>


</div>


</div>



<div class="Labelcon">
  <div class="Label">Property ID</div>
  <div class="Label">Property Type</div>
  <div class="Label">Property Deal Type</div>
  <div class="Labelowner">Property Owner</div>
  <div class="Labeldealer">Property Dealer</div>
  <div class="Label">Proposted Price</div>
  <div class="Label">Property Status</div>
</div>


<div class="Valuecon">
  <div class="Value"><?php echo $row['PropertyID'] ?></div>
  <div class="Value"><?php echo $row['PropertyType'] ?></div>
  <div class="Value"><?php echo $row['PropertyDealType']?></div>
  <div class="Valueowner"><?php echo $row['PropertyOwnerName'] ?></div>
  <div class="Valuedealer"><?php echo $row['PropertyDealerName'] ?></div>
  <div class="Value"><?php echo $row['PropostedPrice'];?></div>
  <div class="Value"><?php echo $row['PropertyStatus'];?></div>
</div>

<?php 
}}
?>
</div>
<p></p>
<center>
<?php $queryemail= "SELECT transactions.AmountPaid, transactions.TaxDeduction, transactions.AmountPayable from remoteemployees, transactions 

                    WHERE RemoteEmployeeEmail ='".$email."' limit 1"; ?>
<div class="Amountpayablepaid">

  <div class="amountpayable">

      <div class="aclabel">Amount Payable:</div>

      <div class="acvalue">

      <?php
       $queryemail_run = $connection->query($queryemail);
  if( $connection->error ) exit( $connection->error );
  while($row=$queryemail_run->fetch_assoc()) 
  {   
      ?>
      <div class="USD">
      <?php echo 'USD '.$row['AmountPayable'];  ?>
      </div>


      </div>
      <br>
    <br>  
  </div>
  <div class="amountpaid">

      <div class="acpaidlable">Tax Deduction:</div>

      <div class="acpaidvalue">

        <div class="USDpaid"><?php echo 'USD '.$row['TaxDeduction']; ?></div>


      </div>

  </div>

  <div class="amountpaid" style="margin-top:22px;">

      <div class="acpaidlable">Amount Paid:</div>

      <div class="acpaidvalue">

        <div class="USDpaid"><?php echo 'USD '.$row['AmountPaid'];}?></div>


      </div>

  </div>

</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code review site. This would be better suited for the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange page. Further more, this question is not general enough as to be useful for anyone else.

Comment: I am not reviewing my code my code has a problem that its copying the header too along records

Answer (score 1):

You start the `while` loop above all HTML, but you need to do it only for table rows `<div class="Valuecon">`. So move it below to the correct place

Maybe something like this (I'm not a good PHP coder, so it is not tested... but u should get the idea):

```
{
  echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL= ../../spd/myaccount.php">';
  exit();
}
else 
{
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
require_once('../../Admin Panel/db.php');

$query = "SELECT 
   properties.PropertyID,
   properties.PropertyType,
   properties.PropertyDealType,
   properties.Status,
   properties.PropostedPrice,
   properties.PropertyStatus,
   properties.RemoteEmployeeEmail,
   properties.PropertyDealerName,
   properties.PropertyOwnerName,
   remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeID

   FROM remoteemployees,
        properties

   WHERE remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeEmail = properties.RemoteEmployeeEmail   

   AND  properties.RemoteEmployeeEmail = '".$email."'

   AND  properties.Status= 'Active'

   AND  properties.PropertyStatus= 'APPROVED'


   ORDER BY properties.PropertyID
   ";


         ?>


<html>
<head>
<style>
.wrapper
{
  width:1250px;
  height:auto;
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius:5px;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  -ms-border-radius:5px;
  font-family:"Arial";
}
.wrapper .header
{
  width:1250px;
  height:30px;
  border-bottom:solid 1px #f0eeee;
  margin:auto 0;
  margin-bottom:12px;
}
.wrapper .header div
{
text-decoration:none;
color:#000;
}
.wrapper .header div a
{
text-decoration:none;
color:#000;
}
.wrapper .Labelcon
{
  width:1250px;
  height:29px;
}

.wrapper .Labelcon .Label
{
  width:135px;
  height:20px;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  border-left:1px solid #f0eeee;
  font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size:14.3px;
  font-weight:bold;

}

.wrapper .Labelcon .Labelowner
{
  width:150px;
  height:20px;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  border-left:1px solid #f0eeee;
  font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size:14.3px;
  font-weight:bold;

}

.wrapper .Labelcon .Labeldealer
{
  width:150px;
  height:20px;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  border-left:1px solid #f0eeee;
  font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size:14.3px;
  font-weight:bold;

}

.wrapper .Valuecon
{
  width:1250px;
  height:29px;
  border-top:solid 1px #ccc;
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.wrapper .Valuecon .Value
{
  width:135px;
  height:20px;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  border-left:1px solid #f0eeee;
  font-size:14px;
}
.wrapper .Valuecon .Valueowner
{
  width:150px;
  height:20px;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  border-left:1px solid #f0eeee;
  font-size:14px;
}

.wrapper .Valuecon .Valuedealer
{
  width:150px;
  height:20px;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  border-left:1px solid #f0eeee;
  font-size:14px;
}

.Amountpayablepaid
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:375px;
    height:120px;
    font-family:"Arial";
    padding:8px;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
    border-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    -ms-border-radius:6px;
}
.Amountpayablepaid .amountpayable
{
    width:600px;
    height:30px;
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.Amountpayablepaid .amountpayable .aclabel
{
    width:145px;
    line-height: 30px;
    height:30px;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
    float:left;
}
.Amountpayablepaid .amountpayable .acvalue
{
    width:445px;
    height:30px;
    float:right;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.Amountpayablepaid .amountpayable .acvalue .USD
{
    width:218px;
    height:30px;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
    float:left;
}

.Amountpayablepaid .amountpayable .acvalue .AFN
{
    width:218px;
    height:30px;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
    float:right;
}
.Amountpayablepaid .amountpaid
{
    width:600px;
    height:30px;
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
  float:left;
}

.Amountpayablepaid .amountpaid .acpaidlable
{
    width:145px;
    height:30px;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
    float:left;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.Amountpayablepaid .amountpaid .acpaidvalue
{
    width:445px;
    height:30px;
    float:right;
}
.Amountpayablepaid .amountpaid .acpaidvalue .USDpaid
{
    width:218px;
    height:30px;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
    float:left;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.Amountpayablepaid .amountpaid .acpaidvalue .AFNpaid
{
    width:218px;
    height:30px;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
    float:right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">
<div style="float:left;"><font color="#000000">Welcome: <?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?> 
</font>
</div>
<div style="float:right; color:#999; width:600px; margin-left:155px;">


<a href="#" style="  font: 15px verdana;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  cursor:pointer;">My Contract Copy</a>

<a href="#" style="  font: 15px verdana;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  cursor:pointer;">My Property List</a>

<a href="#" style="  font: 15px verdana;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  cursor:pointer;">My Trans.History</a>

<a href="Remote Employee profile.php?RemoteEmployeeid=<?php echo $row['RemoteEmployeeID'] ?>" style="  font: 15px verdana;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  cursor:pointer;">My Profile</a>

<a href="logout.php" style="  font: 15px verdana;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  cursor:pointer;">Logout</a>


</div>


</div>



<div class="Labelcon">
  <div class="Label">Property ID</div>
  <div class="Label">Property Type</div>
  <div class="Label">Property Deal Type</div>
  <div class="Labelowner">Property Owner</div>
  <div class="Labeldealer">Property Dealer</div>
  <div class="Label">Proposted Price</div>
  <div class="Label">Property Status</div>
</div>
<php


  $query_run = $connection->query($query);
  if( $connection->error ) exit( $connection->error );
  while($row=$query_run->fetch_assoc()) {
                $count      =   $queryrun->num_rows;          // Taking the number of queries returened by the result
                $array[]    =   $res; 
  ?>

<div class="Valuecon">
  <div class="Value"><?php echo $row['PropertyID'] ?></div>
  <div class="Value"><?php echo $row['PropertyType'] ?></div>
  <div class="Value"><?php echo $row['PropertyDealType']?></div>
  <div class="Valueowner"><?php echo $row['PropertyOwnerName'] ?></div>
  <div class="Valuedealer"><?php echo $row['PropertyDealerName'] ?></div>
  <div class="Value"><?php echo $row['PropostedPrice'];?></div>
  <div class="Value"><?php echo $row['PropertyStatus'];?></div>
</div>

<?php 
}}
?>
</div>
<p></p>
<center>
<?php $queryemail= "SELECT transactions.AmountPaid, transactions.TaxDeduction, transactions.AmountPayable from remoteemployees, transactions 

                    WHERE RemoteEmployeeEmail ='".$email."' limit 1"; ?>
<div class="Amountpayablepaid">

  <div class="amountpayable">

      <div class="aclabel">Amount Payable:</div>

      <div class="acvalue">

      <?php
       $queryemail_run = $connection->query($queryemail);
  if( $connection->error ) exit( $connection->error );
  while($row=$queryemail_run->fetch_assoc()) 
  {   
      ?>
      <div class="USD">
      <?php echo 'USD '.$row['AmountPayable'];  ?>
      </div>


      </div>
      <br>
    <br>  
  </div>
  <div class="amountpaid">

      <div class="acpaidlable">Tax Deduction:</div>

      <div class="acpaidvalue">

        <div class="USDpaid"><?php echo 'USD '.$row['TaxDeduction']; ?></div>


      </div>

  </div>

  <div class="amountpaid" style="margin-top:22px;">

      <div class="acpaidlable">Amount Paid:</div>

      <div class="acpaidvalue">

        <div class="USDpaid"><?php echo 'USD '.$row['AmountPaid'];}?></div>


      </div>

  </div>

</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have a Welcome point also check my code......Welcome: <?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>

Comment: I am not sure if I understand.. this part seems to be fine

Comment: No without while condition the welcome point is giving error of undefined..........

Comment: Andrew is saying that your loop starts before you start outputting things. Which means each time your loop runs once, you're getting another copy of `<html><head>....`. You need to only put your loop around the content that you want looped.